# Set filter model before set datasource for ag-grid server side row mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have probelm with ag-grid in Server side rowe mode in React
I want initialize filters before first api call for rows.
So on grid ready method I create filter model and set it in gridApi, next I create server side datesource

```
const onGridReady = useCallback((params: GridReadyEvent) => {
 const filterModel = getFilterModel() 
 params.api.setFilterModel(filterModel)

 const datasource = createServerSideDatasource()
 params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource)

 setGridApi(params.api)
 setColumnApi(params.columnApi)
}, [])

const createServerSideDatasource: () => IServerSideDatasource = () => {
 return {
   getRows: async (params) => {
     const response = await getTableRows(params.request) //api call
     if (response.success) {
       params.success({ rowData: response.rows, rowCount: response.lastRow 
     })
    } else {
      params.fail()
     }
},}}
```

Ag-grid call api twice, once with empty filters, and next with my filters
I want call api only once with my filters, perhaps there is different way to set default/initialize filters in ag-grid than api.setFilterModel because I guess that put in internal event loop

1. setdatasource
2. call getRows
3. setFilter
4. trigger call getRows